# iOS How to reset Text Fields at the press of a send button

Tags: ios, email, uitextfield, uitextview

Is there anyway to reset all the text fields in 1 viewcontroller once a send button has been pressed?

**Update**

Just tried adding this to my app to reset the textfields:

```
- (IBAction)resetAction:(id)sender {
    for (UITextField *textField in self.view.subviews) {
        textField.text = @"";
    }
}
```

When the button is pressed it crashes the app and brings up the error

"terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Having looked at other peoples questions with this report they seem to have forgotten to un link a deleted element. However I have unlinked everything and even created a new app just for this just to make sure its not that and it is still throwing this error at me when I push the button.

**UPDATE**

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
}
- (IBAction)resetAction:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}



    - (IBAction)resetAction:(id)sender {
        for (UITextField *textField in self.view.subviews) {
            textField.text = @"";
        }
    }- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more flexibility and cleaner code, loop over each UIView in the self.view.subviews array, check if it's of UITextField class. If it is, cast them to a UITextField and clear it's text by setting it to an empty string.

```
 for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)view;
        textField.text = @"";
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but it is giving me an error when i press the button. Please see my latest code update.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint and see what the error really is ? The NSException crash is a generic one, so it's hard to tell what the problem is just by looking at it. Also, i think the crash is most likely not related to this.

Comment: This is the only thing in my app other than the IBAction in the .h file. Do I need to reference the textfields in any way, could this be why its not working?

Comment: This code basically loops through each UITextField on your ViewController's view and sets it's text to an empty string. It's safe and i am sure this is not the reason of your crash. Try to NSLog something in your IBAction implementation and see if it still crashes. (Don't forget to comment the code above).

Comment: Sure. Copy the header and the implementation file and paste them into Pastebin.com. Also for "Syntax Highlighting" on Pastebin, choose Objective-C, for better readability.

Comment: I've never used Pastebin before so hopefully i've done it right? http://pastebin.com/8R6dmUPY Thank you very much.

Comment: Ok. Look at the example answer i've written for you. Rather than changing text field's text property to nil, i clear it by setting it to an empty string. Nil and @"" are not the same thing! Setting it to nil means you're setting it to nothing, while the text property is an NSString. That should fix your problem.

Comment: Sorry that is something else i'd tried and had accidentally left in. It still has the same effect with @"" or nil.

Comment: Where are you allocating and initializing your text field ? In viewDidLoad you should do: myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init]; ,where myTextField is an IBOutlet of your text field. This should make it work.

Comment: Any chance you could update your answer to show me where? I've tried but still comes up with the same problem.

Comment: Done. Let me know if this problem continues.

Comment: I've added my full code into my question. Can you have a look and see if there is anything in there that could be causing the problem? If not it must be how I am linking things. At present I am linking my Button in ViewController with resetAction. I'm not linking any of the three textfields to anything, is this correct?

Comment: Replace the code in the IBAction with: NSLog(@"Test"); If you won't see "Test" in the console, remove the IBAction and add it again. Also, move the textfield initialization bellow the [super viewDidLoad]; method

Comment: When I swap for NSLog(@"Test") I do see Test come up in the console.

Comment: Can you post the full crash message ?

Comment: This is the message it comes up with:  libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.

Comment: and it goes to this line in the main.m file:   @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56464/discussion-between-sebyddd-and-paulh).

Answer (score 0):

Very simple way to do this is to control+click and drag your textfields you want cleared into your

```
@interface

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtClearAfterSubmit1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtClearAfterSubmit2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtClearAfterSubmit3;

@end
```

then here's the method that'll handle it once it's called:

```
    - (void)clearThisTextboxInput
    {
        self.txtClearAfterSubmit1.text = @"";
        self.txtClearAfterSubmit2.text = @"";
        self.txtClearAfterSubmit3.text = @"";
    }
```

Comment: it'll explicitly clear the ones you tell it to. I updated it to clear 3 textfields.

Comment: How do I add this code to create a separate reset button?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this solution:**

Call by using following method `[self UITextFieldClearAll]`

```
- (void)UITextFieldClearAll
{
    for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
           UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)view;
           textField.text = @"";
        }
    }
}
```